# Issue in accessing googleapis (MAPS) from Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, plsql, google-api, database-connection

I am trying to use google maps API to get the LAT and LON details  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/XML?components=postal_code:1080|country:BE&key = "My Key" ".

I wanted to run this from Oracle Database, for which i need to add a ACL entry to oracle database, but when i try to add the ACL i get error notification, as show below

```
BEGIN
  dbms_network_acl_admin.CREATE_ACL(
    acl => 'ACL_GM.xml',
    description => 'ACL FOR GOOGLE MAPS API',
    principal => 'ADM_KSVIJAYA',
    is_grant => TRUE,
    privilege => 'connect',
    start_date => NULL,
    end_date => NULL);
  COMMIT;
END;

PL/SQL PROCEDURE successfully completed.

BEGIN
  dbms_network_acl_admin.ASSIGN_ACL(
    acl => 'ACL_GM.xml',
    host => 'https://maps.googleapis.com',
    lower_port => NULL,
    upper_port => NULL);      
  COMMIT;
END;

BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-24244: invalid host or port for access control list (ACL) assignment
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN", line 164
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN", line 485
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

How to avoid the error?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be passing the URL as the `host` parameter; as the name suggests it should just be the host (name or IP) part of the URL. The protocol is enabled by the port number parameter(s), and for https only you would need to specify port 443.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_networkacl_adm.htm#ARPLS67225) says:

> host - Host to which the ACL is to be assigned. The host can be the name or the IP address of the host. A wildcard can be used to specify a domain or a IP subnet. The host or domain name is case-insensitive.
>
> lower_port - Lower bound of a TCP port range if not NULL
>
> upper_port - Upper bound of a TCP port range. If NULL, lower_port is assumed

In this case as you're accessing an external resource it should be the fully qualified domain name. So you can do:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.UNASSIGN_ACL (
acl => 'ACL_GM.xml',
host => 'maps.googleapis.com',
lower_port => 443,
upper_port => 443);
COMMIT;
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Or you can leave `upper_port` null which will have the same effect.